# how to add a xaml button in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, button

So I created a button in xaml (made a rectangle > right click > create control > button)

I can add it when I am in the xaml designer part of expression blend, but I cant figure out how to create them programmatically in c#.

supposed I named the new button btn_openRecent, then I want to do something like this:

```
btn_openRecent newBtn = new btn_openRecent();
```

Can I do this? I have saved it as an application resource, if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: "but I cant figure out how to them programmatically in c#."
Create them? Interact with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CustomButton is either a `UserControl` or a regular Button with a customized `Template`

If it's a UserControl, you can use

```
MyCustomButton newBtn = new MyCustomButton();
```

If it's a template (more likely scenario) you would create a regular button and apply a style or a template

```
Button newBtn = new Button();
newBtn.Template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("MyCustomButtonTemplate");
// Or if your Template is defined in a Style
newBtn.Style= (Style)FindResource("MyCustomButtonStyle");
```

Comment: Thanks!! it was the last one:

Comment: newBtn.Style= (Style)FindResource("MyCustomButtonStyle");

Answer (score 2):

In XAML, you declare instances of class `Button`, and assign values to some properties. So, the object created in XAML as

```
<Button Click="OnClick">Test</Button>
```

can be created in C# as

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = "Test";
b.Click += OnClick;
```

If you have put something into the application's resources, you can get it by using

```
Button b = (Button)Application.Current.Resources["key"];
```

But I wouldn't recommend such a technique, since the button cannot be reused more than once.

Note that usually XAML serves one more purpose: putting the control into some another control. So the code like

```
<Grid>
    <Button>Test</Button>
</Grid>
```

is expressed in C# as

```
Grid g = new Grid();
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = "Test";
g.Children.Add(b);
```

Comment: hmm..I can create the Button object, but I cannot create an instance of my own custom button..

Comment: @Toadums: what is "custom button"? Is it just a button with some properties assigned to some values, or a class derived from Button?